# How can I manually (programatically) verify a server is trusted via a bridge certificate?

Tags: .net-core, tcpclient, tls1.2, pki, ca

I need to verify that a server is trusted in the machine root certificate store but need to accommodate the scenario that a bridge CA could be used.

[According to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback?view=netframework-4.7.2), this method of using a TCPClient, then opening the socket seems to be the most preferred way to inspect a SSL Stream's certificate.

When my function hits the `ValidateServerCertificate` function, I intend to inspect the chain object to determine if a Root certificate is stored in the trusted root certificate store on the computer.  Easy enough.

The complexity (and lack of knowledge) comes in when I need to follow a 
"bridge certificate" that is used to cross sign multiple PKI trees.  I'm unsure if the bridge certificate will appear in the local store, the chain, or some other place (if at all).

Furthermore I'm unsure how to follow the branching logic that may occur, since the bridge can occur at any level of the tree.

Suggestions, direction, or a flowchart is welcome

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sockittome
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string machineName = "pesecpolicy.bankofamerica.com";

            // Create a TCP/IP client socket.
            // machineName is the host running the server application.
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(machineName, 443); 

            // Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                client.GetStream(),
                false,
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                null
                );
            // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(machineName);
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
                if (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
                client.Close();
                return;
            }

        }

        // The following method is invoked by the RemoteCertificateValidationDelegate.
        public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
              object sender,
              X509Certificate certificate,
              X509Chain chain,
              SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            // How do I verify the root certificate is installed? 
            // What is the simple way (check certificate hash in the computer store)?
            // What is the complete way (look for bridge certificates ?????)          

            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;

            Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

            // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is all that you care about that it chains to a trusted root? Or are you trying to _avoid_ any sort of bridging / cross-certification?

Comment: @bartonjs This is a diagnostic script that should identify if the trust is functional or not, and if that trust is working (or failing) because a bridge is (is not) present.  The desired outcome depends on the environment (prod, test, legacy) and deployment state of the machine (provisioning, final)

Comment: If you simply don’t register a handler the it will throw if the cert isn’t trusted. If you care about bridging / cross-signing specifically you’ll need to define how you want to identify the bridge vs the “original”/“expected” path. So the bool is easy, the why is hard (and needs more policy from you to define it)

Comment: I'm creating a troubleshooting script suitable for sysadmins who deploy the product in various environments, and aren't aware of all the details that can cause a TLS connection to fail during build. (GPO, trusted root, registry settings for Schannel,/TLS, SSL Proxy/Bluecoat, and deployment agents like Tivoli that adjust system settings).  The only scenario I'm missing now is the root-trust problem, as complex as it may be